# 100 reputation, yet cannot answer protected question (reputation > 10)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have a reputation of 100 (by virtue of being trusted on other sites). However, I cannot answer the following protected question 
[How can I make my kids passionate in science while being religious?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/19238/how-can-i-make-my-kids-passionate-in-science-while-being-religious) which requires me to have more than 10 reputation. 
Either the message should be changed, or the calculation.

Comment: This is more of a general SE improvement (the protected question process is not unique to Parenting). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238082/unable-to-answer-protected-question-despite-having-enough-reputation

Comment: @Erica It's perfectly permissible for these sorts of questions to be asked on site meta; there's no particular requirement to post them to [meta.se].

Comment: Agreed, it was more an observation that we aren't unique in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

The message says you must have earned 10 reputation **on this site**.

[image]

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati) for more information.

Comment: Thought I'd add the screenshot in for you Karl :-)

Comment: I read the linked thread, but I still find the verbiage unclear. It should say "you must have earned at least 10 reputation from [Stackname]" or something similar. Because when you have trusted user bonus, you *do* have 10+ reputation on the local stack *and* on the "site" (which is technically stackexchange.com). But, it doesn't seem like it's going to be changed anytime soon.

Comment: If that's the intent, I'm not sure it is productive.  I'm sure a lot of people are like me, doing a lot on some topics and only a little on others.  Meaning they'll never achieve very many points on those topics.  On the other hand, if someone is on a topic much, getting ten points is trivial and thus "protection" really isn't.  If you want quality, enticing people to do ten points worth of uselessness ...

Comment: @WGroleau Ten points is one upvote on an answer, or two upvotes on a question, or five edits. It doesn't mean you need to have those points in a [tag:toddler] question to answer a [tag:toddler] question. Protection typically goes onto questions that are attracting a significant volume of low-quality answers anyway.